# Entity Framework SaveChanges each 100 inserts

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm inserting several data in our DB like:

```
forech ........
{
 try
 {
   //..process new item from external data
   //..assign data to the new item
   db.MyTable.Add(theNewItem)
   i++;
   if ((i % 100) == 0) db.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
   //ignore the error... can be duplicated row
   errors++;
 }
} //end foreach

if (db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()) db.SaveChanges();
```

For performance Im saving in the DB each 100 records added.
My question is:

If in the next 100 records, 1 is duplicated, this give me an error. But... the others 99 is saved correctly?

I cant verify this right now, I'm not in the office and the process is running importing the data (aprox. 1 million)

Comment: So you kick off some code, run home and ask SO to mentally debug it for you? ;-) Your actual question has been answered before. `SaveChanges()` does so in a transaction, so if one record in that transaction fails for whatever reason, none of the records will be saved. So you can run the import again next monday.

Comment: Let us know when you get back to the office.

Comment: No. My code is saving each single record. (not 100). And the performance is a bit slow. I just read about save each 100 records to improve perf. and jump this question for me. Thanks anyway. I'll check next monday. Thanks.

Comment: Side note: keeping one context instance (`db`) defeats one of the purposes of saving in batches. You should renew the context for each batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is two-fold.

First is the answer to *"What does `SaveChanges()` do"*? This method will get all the records from the change tracker, and write them to the database in a transaction. It will roll back the transaction if any error occurs during either of those processes (collecting and saving). [This is documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792(v=vs.110).aspx).

Now you know this, your question actually is whether the successful operations within a rolled back transaction get committed. They don't, that's entirely what transactions are for. So if 1 record out of 100 inserts gives an error, 0 get saved.

Regarding your comment, you're actually looking for a way to bulk insert records. Look up "bulk copy", as suggested in [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework). Note that this still won't work if any insert fails. Sanitize your data before attempting to insert.

Comment: @YuriMorales, don't just accept the first answer that comes along.. it is certainly possible to change the entitystate of the entries that are being tracked. review `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where( entry => entry.State == EntityState.added);` or `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where( entry => entry.State == EntityState.added);`

Comment: @Brett which question is that answering?

Comment: @CodeCaster, indeed.. my comment doesn't answer the 'yes' or 'no' question being asked.. it addresses the inferred question, how can I omit duplicate entries when doing a SaveChanges method call on the DbContext..

Comment: @Brett you should fix that before adding them to the change tracker. If you add a record in batch one, and the same record in batch two that won't help, neither if the duplicate is already in the database.

Comment: I totally agree, I would not allow a duplicate to be added in the first place, if such a contraint exists.. whether it's buisness or system.